# give animation effect when click button on galleryview android

Tags: android, animation, gallery

When I use Gallery widget, how do I get animate when I click a button to move from one picture to another??

Here is my screenshot of my gallery

[image]

When I swipe I got an animation like bounce effect, but when I click the prev and the next button, the picture just change without any animation.

Is there any way to attach some animation like slide efefct or something???

and here is my code

```
bnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (selectedImagePosition < Imgid.length - 1) {
                ++selectedImagePosition;
            }
            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
            gallery.startAnimation(grow);
        }
    });

bprev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {
                --selectedImagePosition;
            }
            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
        }
    });
```

Thanks